# Dropping a value from a character vector based on an index value in R

Tags: r, filter

I have a character vector that I need to drop a specific one from it based on an index value. Here is a sample:

```
index <- as.integer(2)

object <- c("(G1, 70, Slope[1]) = 0.0;" , "(G1, 70, Slope[2]) = 0.0;",  "(G1, 70, Slope[3]) = 0.0;")

    > object
[1] "(G1, 70, Slope[1]) = 0.0;" "(G1, 70, Slope[2]) = 0.0;" "(G1, 70, Slope[3]) = 0.0;"
```

The index value is `2` so I need to drop the second value `Slope[index]` which has 2 inside of the `Slope[2]`.

The desired output would be :

```
> object2
[1] "(G1, 70, Slope[1]) = 0.0;" "(G1, 70, Slope[3]) = 0.0;"
```

Any ideas on this?

Thanks

Comment: `object[-index]` ?

Comment: it seems to look complicated but actually, it is so simple, thanks for your quick solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `extract` from `magrittr`:

```
magrittr::extract(object, -index)

# [1] "(G1, 70, Slope[1]) = 0.0;" "(G1, 70, Slope[3]) = 0.0;"
```

Or the easiest is given by @akrun with basic subsetting:

```
object[-index]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use grep to find the object(s) that you want to delete.

```
pattern = paste(c("[", index, "]"), collapse="")
object = object[-grep(pattern, object)]
object
[1] "(G1, 70, Slope[1]) = 0.0;" "(G1, 70, Slope[3]) = 0.0;"
```